# How to override ApiController's built in Model State handling for a custom error handler middleware

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5

So I have a .NET 5 web api with a custom error handler middle ware that looks like this:

```cs
        public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

        public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next(context);
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                var response = context.Response;
                response.ContentType = "application/json";
                var responseModel = new Response<string>() { Succeeded = false, Message = error?.Message };

                switch (error)
            {
                    case ConflictException:
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
                        break;

                    case ApiException:
                        // custom application error
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        break;

                    case ValidationException e:
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
                        responseModel.Errors = e.Errors;
                        break;

                    case KeyNotFoundException:
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
                        break;

                    default:
                        // unhandled error
                        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                        break;
                }
                var result = JsonSerializer.Serialize(responseModel);

                await response.WriteAsync(result);
            }
        }
    }
```

It works fine across the board, save for when I have a model binding error. When I hit an endpoint with an invalid model (e.g. send an int for a datetime) this middleware doesn't get hit. I know this is happening because of the built in behavior of `ApiController`, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to bypass it.

- I confirmed my app registration is the first item in my `Configure` method in `Startup`
- I tried suppressing model state like so, but my endpoint just throws a 500 before hitting my middleware instead.

  ```cs
  services.AddControllers()
      .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options =>
      {
          // ...
          options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
          // ...
      }
  ```

I've seen a ton of articles and responses addressing this with attribute filters, but that is **not** something I want to implement as it would split my logic between different areas of my app.

Comment: The problem is that the error is actually at the type resolution and controller action resolution level, so in the routing _before_ the controller action is selected. This is because the action method is resolved from the types by default, not the other way around

Comment: So one option is to create your own route handler and use your own logic to select the action endpoint based on the route, and not the type of the parameters.